# Multi-part form data in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to use react-admin to send data to my custom API. I want to send files, I can see that there is , I'd like to send that data as multi-part form data. I have come across [the base64 encoding help page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#extending-a-data-provider-example-of-file-upload), as a newcomer to react, it is hard for me to figure out what I need to do to turn it in to multi-part form data.

If someone could walk me through the code that makes it work, that'd be great! I'm here to learn.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is my solution:

```js
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import restServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const servicesHost = 'http://my-services-host';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};

const dataProvider = restServerProvider(servicesHost, httpClient);

const myDataProfider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    create: (resource, params) => {
        if (resource !== 'resource-with-file' || !params.data.theFile) {
            // fallback to the default implementation
            return dataProvider.create(resource, params);
        }

        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('paramOne', params.data.paramOne);
        formData.append('paramTwo', params.data.paramTwo);
        formData.append('theFile', params.data.theFile.rawFile);

        return httpClient(`${servicesHost}/${resource}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        }).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
        }));
    }
};

export default myDataProfider;
```